# Parse nested json data to JQUERY variables used in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I had a MySQL data ChartJS graph via a flat JSON output from PHP.
The ChartJS issues the following code:

```
function showGraph()
{
    {
        $.post("data.php?id=0",
        function (data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            const date = [];
            const time = [];
            const temperature = [];
            const humidity = [];
            //const name = [];

            for (var i in data) {
                date.push(data[i].date);
                time.push(data[i].time);
                temperature.push(data[i].temperature);
                humidity.push(data[i].humidity);
                name.push(data[i].name);
            }
```

The PHP script gives flat JSON data, like:

```
{
    "timestamp": "1582877101",
    "time": "09:05",
    "temperature": "18.90",
    "humidity": "50.70"
},
{
    "timestamp": "1582877161",
    "time": "09:06",
    "temperature": "18.90",
    "humidity": "50.70"
},
```

Since the JSON changed to nested data, my graph doesn't work anymore. The new nested JSON looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "Logger 0",
        "data": [
            {
                "date": "2020-02-28",
                "time": "09:05",
                "temperature": "18.90",
                "humidity": "50.70"
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-02-28",
                "time": "09:06",
                "temperature": "18.90",
                "humidity": "50.70"
            }
```

How can I parse the nested JSON data to JQUERY variables again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
$.getJSON("data.php?id=<?php printf($id)?>",
function (data)
{
    const date = [];
    const time = [];
    const temperature = [];
    const humidity = [];
    const name = data[0].name;

    data[0].data.forEach(element => {
        date.push(element.date);
        time.push(element.time);
        temperature.push(element.temperature);
        humidity.push(element.humidity);
    })
```

So I had add **data[0].** to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since `data` is now an attribute of your JSON response, you can access it via [ES6 destructuring](https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#h_B372u36cp6). Note that `data`is now an array, hence you have to use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach), like so:

```js
$.post('data.php?id=0', ({ name, data }) => {
    console.log(name, data);
    const date = [];
    const time = [];
    const temperature = [];
    const humidity = [];

    data.forEach(element => {
        date.push(element.date);
        time.push(element.time);
        temperature.push(element.temperature);
        humidity.push(element.humidity);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but issuing your code creates a complete blank screen, instead of a graph with no data. I think that step 1 is making the code work again, step 2 is upgrading to ES6.